# Relative path in Xcode generated DWARF file

Tags: swift, xcode, dwarf, dsym

When I compile my swift framework `MyFramework` I makes so that Xcode produces `MyFramework.framework` (the compiled framework) and `MyFramework.framework.dSYM` (the dSYM file).

By running  `dwarfdump myframework.framework.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/MyFramework` I've noticed that all the paths to the source files are absolute paths.

This makes it impossible to share these two artefacts (together with the source code) with my colleagues and allow them to use the compiled framework and being able to debug their code properly. More precisely they are not able to step-in inside the framework with the debugger.

For this reason they need recompile the framework which is very inconvenient.

Is there a way to modify the DWARF to edit these paths or even better to convince Xcode to use relative path in the DWARF file?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not aware of a way to change the paths stored in the dSYM or to make them relative, I can offer a way to work around the issue and be able to debug with those symbols on an arbitrary machine with source code in a different base path.

Once you find out what the original path is (e.g. /Users/rob/src/Project), and you have the code for that library in e.g. /Users/luka/Sources/Project, then you can issue this lldb command, which will replace *for that session of the debugger* the original path with your path:

```
settings set target.source-map /Users/rob/src/Project /Users/luka/Sources/Project
```

Unfortunately you'll need to run this command for each debugging session. To do that, you can create a breakpoint in your *main*, which runs that command and continues execution without stopping.

To find the original source path you can either use `dwarfdump` as you mention, or you can look up a symbol you know is in that binary from lldb with `im loo -v -n MySymbol` or through other parameters of the command (depending on the type of symbol you're trying to use).

Comment: This is a nice trick. But we're having the same issue in Playgrounds. Is there an equivalent command for Playgrounds?